# Is there a Python method to access all non-private and non-builtin attributes of a class?

Tags: python, private, public, built-in

I would like to call a method to give me a dict of all of the "non-private" (I use the term "private" somewhat loosely here since it does not really exist in Python) and non-builtin attributes (i.e. those that do not begin with a single or double underscore) on a class.  Something like vars(MyClass) that would return only the "public" attributes on that class.

I'm aware that

```
from M import *
```

does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore. (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id25)  How does import implement that? Via a builtin function or just by checking for underscores?  What is the pythonic way to do this?

Example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        do_stuff()
    def _private(self):
        print 'private'
    def __gets_name_mangled(self:
        print 'becomes _MyClass__gets_name_mangled()'
    def public(self):
        print 'public'
```

If I do

```
vars(MyClass).keys()
```

I get

```
['_MyClass__gets_name_mangled', '__module__', '_private', '__doc__', '__dict__', '__weakref__', 'public', '__init__']
```

How can I get only

```
['public']
```

Or do I just need to check for underscores myself?  It just seems like there would be a pythonic way to do this.

For more on underscores and double underscores, see:
[What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python)

Comment: `vars(MyClass).keys()` is `dir(MyClass)`

Comment: I don't know of any function that does this. There's always: `[f for f in dir(MyClass) if not f.startswith('_')]`

Comment: @Elazar if my understanding is correct, dir(MyClass) will return attributes of classes that are subclassed by MyClass (if MyClass happened to subclass something) in addition to those defined inside MyClass, while vars(MyClass) only returns those attributes defined inside MyClass.  Subtle difference.  But original question stands.

Comment: Yes, you are right. And I believe @Blender gave you the only answer there is.

Comment: @Blender that is certainly a way to do it...I suppose if it's the only way, then it must be the Pythonic way (lest the Pythonic way be "tuck tail and retreat").  In which case I'd give you credit for an answer if you posted as an answer...

Comment: Actually, the Pythonic way is to define a function: `def public_vars(klass): return [f for f in vars(MyClass) if f[0] != '_']`

Comment: Double underscore **doesn't mean private**. It means "use name mangling" which is just a mechanism for this class to keep an attribute that is distinct from the same attribute in any subclasses

Comment: @gnibbler.  good point.  i updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 19):

With a dict comprehension that filters vars()

```
{ k:v for k,v in vars(myObject).items() if not k.startswith('_') }
```

Moved into a function that returns a list of attributes that are not 'soft private' or callables. You can return values if you like by changing to dict comprehension as above

```
def list_public_attributes(input_var):
    return [k for k, v in vars(input_var).items() if
            not (k.startswith('_') or callable(v))]
```

Comment: Isn't 'public' (the desired output) a callable here? Why is this a filtering criteria?

Comment: Please note that `vars` _will_ filter the "magic" (aka d'under) methods, unlike `dir`. For "private" / s'under, the filter shown here is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it would be unpythonic for such function to exists - because "officially" there is no private or protected fields/properties in Python.

While it makes sense to throw away module attributes with leading underscores (which are usually some implementation details) during `import *` from some module*, it is not useful in context of any other object.

So, if you need to list only "public" methods/attributes of an object, just iterate through result of `dir` and drop names with leading underscores.

---

* "during `import *` from some module'"

Usually it is not the best practice.  Consider the next example:

module `A` has `a1` and `a2` defined

module `B` has `b1` and `b2` defined

This code in module `C` works as expected:

```
from A import a1, a2
from B import *
```

Imagine we add function `a1` in module `B`.  Now suddenly module `C` is broken, although we haven't touched it.

Comment: out of curiosity: does import * just check for leading underscores in the same way as @Blender suggested that I do it?

Comment: @andy - import * is considered bad practice because you can never be sure of what you exactly import, which in turn can create name conflicts and possible unintended use of methods which have been imported using the *. It is always better to explicityly import every method separately, or to simply refer to them from the common namespace.

Comment: I think it's the only way you add an implicit binding without using `exec`.

Comment: I see.  You're saying _calling_ `import *` is bad practice (that makes sense). I thought you were saying that the _implementation_ of `import *` (ignoring attributes with leading underscores) was bad practice (because it followed the public/private paradigm). Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @andy Got it.  Edited the answer to remove ambiguity.

Comment: @Elazar Yep, this is a nice observation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this function:

```
def print_all_public_fields(obj):
    print(obj)
    for a in dir(obj):
        if not a.startswith('_') and not a.isupper():
            print('\t%s = %s' % (a, getattr(obj, a)))
```

I know it's not exactly what you want, but maybe it'll give you some idea.