# How to avoid built-ins showing up when dir is used on my modules

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-import, python-packaging

Can we avoid built-ins showing up when dir is used on a module I created?
Like, in this case, I want to avoid showing up of inbuilt libraries like os, sys, random, struct, time, hashlib etc.

```
>>> import endesive.pdf.cms
>>> dir(endesive.pdf.cms)
['EncodedString', 'SignedData', 'UnencryptedBytes', 'WNumberObject', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_cmath', 'backends', 'codecs', 'datetime', 'hashlib', 'io', 'pdf', 'pkcs12', 'po', 'random', 'sign', 'signer', 'struct', 'sys', 'time']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Python method to access all non-private and non-builtin attributes of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075071/is-there-a-python-method-to-access-all-non-private-and-non-builtin-attributes-of)

Comment: I am asking about ways to avoid showing up of the inbuilt library names that I have imported when a client fires dir on my module

Comment: You're asking **A** module, not **your** module. It's quite a big difference. One implies your things that you implement, the other on any given module.

Comment: OK my bad, but you can create a dummy module with some inbuilt library imports, and let's say your class and check for it.

Comment: I changed your titel and question details accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

State this in module:

```py
import sys
# Your code...
def __dir__():
    return [x for x in globals() if x not in sys.modules]
```

Comment: I am asking about ways to avoid showing up of the inbuilt library names that I have imported when a client fires dir on my module.

Comment: Following error  pops up when adding your code in my module namespace. dir(endesive.pdf.cms)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: What version are you using? I don't see a place that calls a ``list``?

Comment: Using python 3.7.7

Comment: P.S. You should add that line at the end of the module, or ``globals()`` will not be right.  Also, I discovered that stackoverflow might not keep the __s -- check if you entered ``dir`` instead of ``__dir__``.

Comment: Hey man, __dir__ is a magic **method**. you are not supposed to assign a list to it correct me if I am wrong. you just have to override the method in your namespace. it's working now.

Comment: Also, One more question have you used dir before, and for what purpose you have used it. I really want to know.

Comment: @PrinceRoshan  I don't use ``dir`` as much. I only use it to check if I misspelled something (e.g. checking if some name similar is in ``dir(module)``).